# Surjective linear transformation on infinite dimensional vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $V_1,V_2$ be two infinite-dimensional vector spaces and $\phi:V_1\to V_2$ be a linear transformation, such that $\dim\phi(U)=\dim U$, for every finite-dimensional subspace $U\subset V_1$. Is $\phi$ injective?

**EDIT:** I've deleted additional information, as well as my work so far because both were unnecessary, for the reasons described in the comments.

Comment: Your condition on finite dimensional subspaces is already enough to guarantee that $\phi$ is injective

Comment: If  $\dim\phi(U)=\dim U$ for every finite-dimensional subspace $U\subset V_1$,  the restriction of $\phi$ to any finite dimensional subspace is an isomorphism, hence $\phi$ itself is injective, whether it be surjective or not.

Comment: $(1)$doesn't hold for infinite-dimensional subspaces, take for example the linear operator $D$, the derivative map from
$$C^\infty(\Bbb R)\to C^\infty(\Bbb R)$$

Then this map is clearly surjective, but it is not injective as the derivative of any constant is $0$

Comment: @emonHR But does $D$ fulfill $\dim D(U)=\dim U$? If I'm not mistaken, $\dim \ker(D)\neq 0$

Comment: @Bernard Thank you very much for the comment, but how can we conclude that "hence $\phi$ itself is injective" from your argument?

Comment: That's because every vector lies in a finite dimensional subspace.

Comment: @Bernard But what about function spaces? There we often times have the property that vectors don't lie in finite-dimensional subspaces, as far as I know.

Comment: Even the subspace they generate??

Comment: @Bernard Oh yes thank you, you're right

Comment: You have to keep in mind that any vector space is a diect limit of finite dimendionzl spaces (actually this is true for modules over a ring, with ‘finite dimensional’ replaced with ‘finitely generated’, since modules do not have a basis in general).

Comment: Right now (given what the comments have said about your condition on subspaces), your question asks “given that a map is injective, what condition allows us to guarantee that surjective implies injectivity”, which doesn’t make much sense. Please update your question so that it is answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v\in V_1$, $v\ne0$; then $\dim\langle v_1\rangle=1$ (the subspace spanned by $v$). By assumption, $\dim\phi(U)=1$, so $\phi(v)\ne0$, otherwise $\phi(U)=\{0\}$.